# firebase dynamic link, send user to website first?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

1. Clicking the received link on an Android device that have the app installed already -> The app opens [great!]
2. Clicking the received link on an Android device that DO NOT have the app installed already -> Google Play opens

I am wondering if I could change the behavior of #2 as the following

Clicking the received link on an Android device that DO NOT have the app installed already -> corresponding web page .

if he clicks "Open in app" -> Google play opnens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to specify custom fallback link. For Android fallback link see [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/create), parameter name `AndroidParameters.setFallbackUrl`.